# Put your finger in the air

Tags: word-usage

What to say when I want to tell someone to show one finger for number one? ' Put your one finger up' is correct or not?

https://www.dreamstime.com/flashcard-number-one-illustration-use-to-study-kid-image116667393

Comment: "Hold up one finger" would be the most natural way to say it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of 'one finger' using finger's respective name might be better.
like:- put your index finger up.
or put your pinky/little finger up when you want to go to washroom.